# f# why I am getting error while trying to print the output?

Tags: f#

I am trying to print the output for the following _reverse_efficient function and when run the program without implementing the last two rows to print the output, then the function compiles fine, but when include those two last two line to print the out put then I get an error. Please I need help to fix this issue, below is my code:

```
Console.Write("Enter your input: ")
let L = Console.ReadLine()

let rec _reverse_efficient L R=
   match L with
   | [] -> R
   |e::rest -> _reverse_efficient rest (e::R)

let Q = _reverse_efficient L []
printfn "Reverse list is: %A" Q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error message:

```
"typecheck: This expression was expected to have type
    ''a list'    
but here has type
    'string'    ".
```

on this line:

```
let Q = _reverse_efficient L []
```

Basically it is complaining that `L` is `string` and not a `list`.
That is because `Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`. You need to convert the input into a `list` somehow before you call `_reverse_efficient`

Comment: Thank you AMieres, could you please show me how to read a list and return a list so that I can pass that user's input list to the function to reverse the list. For example, if user enters 1..4, then the the function _reverse_efficient L R [ ] should read 1, 2, 3, 4 and then reverse these numbers to 4, 3, 2, 1.

Comment: I would suggest using `.Split([| ".." |], System.StringSplitOptions.None)` to get the 2 numbers, converting them to `int` using `int` and then `[a..b]` to get the list.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this f#, I am not sure how to exactly implement your suggestion, I will try.

Comment: Yes, I encourage to try, that is how we learn. You will get it.